# Node.js @slack/webhook issue with Axios

Tags: node.js, axios, slack, es6-modules

I'm trying to use `@slack/webhook` but getting the following error:

```
node -r esm index.js

---------------------
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module .../node_modules/axios/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in null to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/@slack/webhook/dist/IncomingWebhook.js:7:33) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

- Node.js version v20.11.0
- `@slack/webhook` version 7.0.2
- Axios version 1.6.5

Answer (score 0):

`axios@1.x.x` ships only ESM code. So you wont be able to use `require` on them. Instead, as the error message suggests, you can do `const axios = await import('axios')`. Here we are using the dynamic import syntax, and it is available in CJS modules as well.

However, if you would like to persist with `require`, you will need to downgrade axios version to < 1 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios/v/0.27.2)

Comment: Thank you for the comment but it's not my code that uses Axios directly. It's @slack/webhook.

Comment: For a quick resolution, you can use `6.1.0` version of @slack/webhook. It uses a downgraded version of axios

Comment: I'm just wondering how others are using new versions of the @slack/webhook or maybe nobody uses it at all :)